# Convert an int column to bigint with the 4 bytes of padding available

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

If there's 4 bytes of padding that would fit the `bigint` perfectly, is it possible to efficiently convert it on-the-spot by taking advantage of that gap?

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    b SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    c TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    d TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
);
```

I understand that indexes and foreign keys would still be affected, but just wondering about the table itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking if the table heap size would be affected, then no the 4 extra bytes of padding would be used for the bigint, and the table would be unchanged since the following data type (timestamptz) uses 8 bytes and would be placed on the following "column" as it were. This should also hold true for indexes, I believe anything up to 8 bytes will occupy the same space per row.

Tested using postgresql 10:

```
insert into a (c,d) select generate_series(now(), now()+interval '100000 days', interval '1 day'), now();
INSERT 0 100001

select pg_relation_size('a');
 pg_relation_size 
------------------
          5218304
(1 row)

select pg_total_relation_size('a');
 pg_total_relation_size 
------------------------
                7479296
(1 row)


alter table a alter column b type bigint;

select pg_relation_size('a');
 pg_relation_size 
------------------
          5218304
(1 row)

select pg_total_relation_size('a');
 pg_total_relation_size 
------------------------
                7479296
(1 row)
```

Were you to change your id column to smallint, (smallint primary key on table can only have a maximum of 65535 rows, deleting rows would lead to a different issue...) the data size would likewise still not be affected since the following timestamp column could still not be squeezed next to it.

Comment: But doesn't this still rewrite the entire table?

Comment: A rewrite would be required I believe, since the bytes will need to be shifted to the right.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't consider that... the only way this could've even been possible is if integers were stored with the endianness backwards, or if the empty 4-byte padding was before the column.